# Local Network not allowing access to multiple computers

Tags: networking

Not sure if I should ask this question here, but this is a technology community so why not.

I'm running a local network which is setup like this:

Modem -> Access Point -> Switch -> Server/5 other computers

and my problem is the 5 other computers only two computers can have access to the internet (which are connected though Ethernet).

Also, any device that's connected to my wireless network can't access the internet either.

I know it's not a problem from my ISP since two computers are connected to the internet. And I know it's not a wireless problem since my local server can be reached though the access point.

I'm not sure what is the problem since I replaced all the cables, devices, and done tons of resets.

Appreciate your help, or direction to where I can get help.

Comment: This might be a better fit at [Network Engineering Stack Exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) (or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)?) but of course if you can get an answer here, yay!

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all, but my problem was that I used static IP and didn't assign more than three, two computers and a printer. completely a beginner's mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are familiar with computer networks but I think it's a network problem. Maybe your router (modem) can provide only two IPs and that's why only two computers can connect the internet. To verify this you can check what is your IP, and what is your Subnet Mask. Type ipconfig in your cmd and give me your IP and the subnet mask to check if this is the problem or not.